# Keeping text in menu centered despite screen changes

Tags: html, css

This has definitely been asked before, and I apologise. But the solutions just doesn't seem to work for me. I am trying to keep my menu text centered in spite of resolution changes. Also I have a 'home' image thing floating. Is that why it won't work? What is the best way to insert that into the menu bar?

```css
#menu-bar {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  height: 35px;
  left: 0px; 
  top: 0px; 
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index:998;
   position: fixed;
}

.imghome { position: relative; top: -3px; }

#menu-bar li {
  padding: 10px 25px 0px 6px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
  
#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #D6D6D6;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
   <!-- Header -->
<ul id="menu-bar">
  <li><a href="index.html"> <img class="imghome" src="assets/img/home1.png" width="20" height="20" "top="9"></li>
 <li><a href="howtoanalyse.html">How to Analyse   </a></li>
 <li><a href="write.html">How to Write   </a>
 <li><a href="grammar.html">Grammar Slides   </a>
 <li><a href="topics.html">Topics   </a></li> 
 <li><a href="authors.html">Authors   </a></li> 
 <li><a href="information.html">Useful Information   </a></li>
</ul>
```

[Link to js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxxu56w1/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I did was remove the additional quotation mark in the img tag.

As you had mentioned want it to be able to adapt to screen size I removed the fixed height of the background so it will properly change height on smaller screens.

I then removed them from the list so the text can center properly and changed them from: `display:block` to `display:inline-block` so it will dynamically change and lastly I added `text-align: center;` so it will center automatically regardless of screen size.

See the  [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mallettem/bxxu56w1/33/)

Comment: Thanks. What is the reasoning behind turning them into divs?

Comment: Just one div, to contain the text and give it the background you are looking for. The links themselves are still just links

Answer (score 0):

Using a Flexbox in your css will help align your text and adjust it automatically based on screen size.

Try adding:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

to the **#main-bar**.
I would also make some adjustments to the padding to make it look better:

```css
#menu-bar {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px; 
  top: 0px; 
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index:998;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.imghome { position: relative; top: -3px; }

#menu-bar li {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  
  list-style: none;
}
  
#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #D6D6D6;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
   <!-- Header -->
<ul id="menu-bar">
  <li><a href="index.html"> <img class="imghome" src="assets/img/home1.png"  height="20" "top="9"></li>
 <li><a href="howtoanalyse.html">How to Analyse   </a></li>
 <li><a href="write.html">How to Write   </a>
 <li><a href="grammar.html">Grammar Slides   </a>
 <li><a href="topics.html">Topics   </a></li> 
 <li><a href="authors.html">Authors   </a></li> 
 <li><a href="information.html">Useful Information   </a></li>
</ul>
```

More on flexboxes: [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Thanks. It looks great in the snippet, but when I put it into the whole code the "menu categories" are listed vertically instead of horizontally. Hmm.

Comment: display: flex; should by default arrange items horizontally. Maybe you have a css in the parent container that forces it to go vertical (my guess since I don't know how the whole code looks like. Try adding **flex-direction: row;** to #menu-bar after display:flex;. I have updated my answer to reflect this change.